# making ViewPager scroll infinite in android

Tags: java, android

I created a ViewPager with two tabs, but thinking to make even more, for that, I tried first to make my tabs scroll infinitely and unfortunately I am not able to make view pager scroll infinitely. Please help.
/*Using Eclipse*/
These are my classes:

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

ActionBar mActionBar;
ViewPager mPager;
private int focusedPage = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    /** Getting a reference to action bar of this activity */
    mActionBar = getActionBar();

    /** Set tab navigation mode */
    mActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    /** Getting a reference to ViewPager from the layout */
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    /** Getting a reference to FragmentManager */
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();


    /** Defining a listener for pageChange */
    ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener pageChangeListener = new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {              
            super.onPageSelected(position);
            mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position); 


        }

         @Override
         public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
         }

         @Override
         public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
         }
    };

    /** Setting the pageChange listner to the viewPager */
    mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(pageChangeListener);

    /** Creating an instance of FragmentPagerAdapter */
    MyFragmentPagerAdapter fragmentPagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(fm);


    /** Setting the FragmentPagerAdapter object to the viewPager object */
    mPager.setAdapter(fragmentPagerAdapter);

    mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

    /** Defining tab listener */
    ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(Tab arg0,
                android.app.FragmentTransaction arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab,
            android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
            mPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab,
                android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };

    /** Creating Android Tab */
    Tab tab = mActionBar.newTab()
                       .setText("Android")
                       .setIcon(R.drawable.android)
                       .setTabListener(tabListener);

    mActionBar.addTab(tab);

    /** Creating Apple Tab */
    tab = mActionBar.newTab()
                   .setText("Apple")
                   .setIcon(R.drawable.apple)
                   .setTabListener(tabListener);                               

    mActionBar.addTab(tab);        




}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

 public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // on tab selected
        // show respected fragment view
        mPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

}
```

**MyFragmentPagerAdapter.java:**

```
public class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

final int PAGE_COUNT = 2;

/** Constructor of the class */
public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);

}

/** This method will be invoked when a page is requested to create */
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
    Bundle data = new Bundle();
    switch(arg0){

        /** Android tab is selected */
        case 0:
            AndroidFragment androidFragment = new AndroidFragment();                
            data.putInt("current_page", arg0+1);
            androidFragment.setArguments(data);
            return androidFragment;

        /** Apple tab is selected */
        case 1:
            AppleFragment appleFragment = new AppleFragment();
            data.putInt("current_page", arg0+1);
            appleFragment.setArguments(data);
            return appleFragment;   
    }

    return null;
}

/** Returns the number of pages */
@Override
public int getCount() {     
    return PAGE_COUNT;
}   
}
```

To be more clear, I want an output which should look like this:

The tab which is selected should be in the center and others should scroll infinitely:
[image: Scrollable Tabs]

Comment: Hey, did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Remove final for PAGE_COUNT and add the below code :

```
@Override
public int getCount() {     
    return PAGE_COUNT=PAGE_COUNT+1;
}
```

Comment: It will reduce performance, as this code produce more fragment each time scroll ends

Answer (score -1):

Let's assume we have 3 tabs and we want the user to be able to swipe left and right indefinitely.

First, create a very large integer

```
// scroll the list to a pretty large position index so it can be scroll both up and down.
private static final int A_BIG_NUMBER = 1000;
```

Then set the page number to be twice as much as the large integer

```
/**
 * Returns the number of pages
 */
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 2 * A_BIG_NUMBER;
}
```

The trick lays in the getItem method, get the real position by doing the modulus calculation and return the Fragment according to the real position of the tab. So if there are 3 tabs and the position is 999, the real position is 0; when the position is 1000, the real position is 1.

```
 @Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    int realPosition = position % numberOfTabs;

    ... 
}
```

When you are initialising the ViewPager, you want it to swipe to a position where the number is large so the user can swipe back and forth.

We can do this by

```
mPager.setCurrentItem(A_BIG_NUMBER - A_BIG_NUMBER % numberOfTabs);
```

In the case, the `A_BIG_NUMBER` is 1000 and `A_BIG_NUMBER % numberOfTabs` is 1, so  the initial position if the ViewPager is 999. So the getItem(999) will return the Fragment on position 0 ( 999%3 = 0)